# Duplication of a field based on a column

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by, duplicates

I have a table SHIPMENT

```
SHIPMENT       CARTON_ID       ITEM
100             A123           10000243
101             A123           10253456
100             A200           11192423
100             A300           11174523
```

the carton ID is being repeated for two shipments. I want to know which carton ID is getting repeated for more than one distinct shipment ID i.e A123 getting repeated for 100 and 101

```
select carton, count (carton) from shipment
where
carton is not null
group by carton, shipment
having count (carton) > 1
```

what do I need to change in the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only group by the carton, and count its distinct shipments:

```sql
SELECT   carton, COUNT(DISTINCT shipment)
FROM     shipment
GROUP BY carton
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT shipment) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You current `group by` clause generates one row per shipment *and* carton. Basically, you just need to remove `shipment` from the `group by` clause, so you get one group per `carton_id`: you can then check how many rows belong to the group, as you originally intended:

```
select carton_id, count(*)
from shipment
where carton_id is not null
having count(*) > 1
```

If there is a possibility of duplicate `(shipment, carton_id)` tuples, and you don't want to count them twice, you can use `count(distinct shipment)` instead of `count(*)`.